# MS Word line breaks in Java

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I'm building a grammatical text interpreter with a JavaFX GUI where you can just paste your text into a TextArea. This creates something of a problem though, since line breaks from MS Word are somehow formatted in a special way (both paragraphs (ENTER) and line breaks (SHIFT+ENTER).

If I copy the text to a plain .txt file and open it in a browser (tried Chrome, Safari and Firefox), I can copy it again from there without any problem. They somehow fix the issue.
Pasting the text into a new e-mail in Apple's mail and then copying it from there, fixes it, even pasting it into a JEditorPane (java swing), fixes it.
Notepad, TextEdit, Notes and Pages does NOT solve it.

But I need the ability to copy the text directly from a variety of sources and asking people to copy it to somewhere else is just not an option.

I searched for a solution before this post, and the general solution I could find was to replace "\r" with "\r\n", but this doesn't seem to help, as the line break is already lost, as soon as it has been pasted into the TextArea.

A different solution would of course be to simply use a JEditorPane instead of the TextArea, but when I create an AnchorPane and put a JEditorPane into it as a swingComponent, I get an area the size of the initial text, and editing that text on runtime doesn't change the size of that area (which is NOT the area of the contentPane).

Now, I know that I present different solution ideas here, and that I probably should just ask for how to get one specific thing to work, but I'm really getting a headache over this, so weather it's a way to get the contentPane to work properly with the layout, finding a way to make the TextArea keep these linebreaks or even something different is fine. I've just spent too much time trying to solve it now :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7909412/fixing-the-size-of-jeditorpane-content ?

Comment: Apparently MS Word uses a special symbol for line breaks in paragrahps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21590316/regex-remove-line-breaks-if-lookbehind-shows-a-lowercase

Comment: I had a similiar problem a few years back, and while I do not remember the solution, I seem to remember that the line-breaks are not lost just because the TextArea doesn't show them. Did you check that?